# How to return N records after given record ID in an Active Record scope?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Given an Active Record `scope`, how to return N records **after** the given record?

For example, consider we have a list of urban areas sorted by population:

Active record scope:

```
Area.ordered_by_population
```

Returned rows:

```
ID | Area
------------
 9 | Tokyo
 2 | Jakarta
 7 | Seoul
 1 | Delhi
 8 | Shanghai
 4 | Manila
 3 | Karachi
 5 | New York City
 6 | São Paulo
```

Now I need to return 3 next records after ID 8 (Shanghai). So the result will be:

```
4 | Manila
3 | Karachi
5 | New York City
```

The rails call will look like this:

```
Area.ordered_by_population.records_after_id(id: 8, count: 3)
```

So, how do I write this `records_after_id` method?

*Performance requirement:* the approach should handle db tables with 100K records and be relatively fast (I target 1ms on modern laptop).

### Update

Important nuance about this problem noted by Beerlington. I can not use pagination solution for this, unfortunately. I need to return rows after given record. It must by relative to a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `records_after_id` method can be defined as follows

```
    module Pager
      def records_after_id(id:, count:)
        relation = self.dup
        # perform the query and find the index of the id
        offset = relation.pluck(:id).find_index(id)
        # OFFSET LIMIT query starting +1 after the found id
        relation.offset(offset + 1).limit(count)
      end
    end
```

then you can call it as follows

```
    Area.ordered_by_population.extending(Pager).records_after_id(id: 8, count: 3)
```

as a `Relation` is returned it can be extended, like to sum the population of the next 3 records

```
    Area.ordered_by_population
    .extending(Pager)
    .records_after_id(id: 8, count: 3)
    .sum(:population)
```

more info at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-extending

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding the problem, but it sounds like what you want is pagination, and you don't actually care about the ID. I've used the [Kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for this in the past with success. You can do it without the gem too by just changing the `limit` and `offset` in your query, but the gem makes managing that a little more user friendly.

With Kaminari:

```
Area.ordered_by_population.page(1).per(8)
Area.ordered_by_population.page(2).per(8)
Area.ordered_by_population.page(3).per(8)
```

Without Kaminari:

```
Area.ordered_by_population.limit(10).offset(0)
Area.ordered_by_population.limit(10).offset(10)
Area.ordered_by_population.limit(10).offset(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful note. Unfortunately, my use case is not compatible with pagination approach. Problem is - the table is constantly changing: rows are being added. So the content of a page #5 from 10 seconds ago may differ from current content of this page. My client is not a web page where pagination approach does work.